# modify estimator to get numeric values from a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking at the google-research/bert repository. I'm modifying the 'run_pretraining.py' file. I want to get the results of individual lines of the input, what I think is the next_sentence_predictions or the next_sentence_log_probability during evaluation.

This is the method I'm changing. The line I change is marked with a comment:

```
def model_fn_builder(bert_config, init_checkpoint, learning_rate,
                 num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu,
                 use_one_hot_embeddings):
    """Returns `model_fn` closure for TPUEstimator."""

    def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """The `model_fn` for TPUEstimator."""

        tf.logging.info("*** Features ***")
        for name in sorted(features.keys()):
            tf.logging.info("  name = %s, shape = %s" % (name, features[name].shape))

        input_ids = features["input_ids"]
        input_mask = features["input_mask"]
        segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]
        masked_lm_positions = features["masked_lm_positions"]
        masked_lm_ids = features["masked_lm_ids"]
        masked_lm_weights = features["masked_lm_weights"]
        next_sentence_labels = features["next_sentence_labels"]

        is_training = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

        model = modeling.BertModel(
            config=bert_config,
            is_training=is_training,
            input_ids=input_ids,
            input_mask=input_mask,
            token_type_ids=segment_ids,
            use_one_hot_embeddings=use_one_hot_embeddings)

        (masked_lm_loss,
         masked_lm_example_loss, masked_lm_log_probs) = get_masked_lm_output(
            bert_config, model.get_sequence_output(), model.get_embedding_table(),
            masked_lm_positions, masked_lm_ids, masked_lm_weights)

        (next_sentence_loss, next_sentence_example_loss,
         next_sentence_log_probs) = get_next_sentence_output(
            bert_config, model.get_pooled_output(), next_sentence_labels)

        total_loss = masked_lm_loss + next_sentence_loss

        tvars = tf.trainable_variables()

        initialized_variable_names = {}
        scaffold_fn = None
        if init_checkpoint:
            (assignment_map, initialized_variable_names
             ) = modeling.get_assignment_map_from_checkpoint(tvars, init_checkpoint)
            if use_tpu:

            def tpu_scaffold():
                tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment_map)
                return tf.train.Scaffold()

            scaffold_fn = tpu_scaffold
            else:
            tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(init_checkpoint, assignment_map)

        tf.logging.info("**** Trainable Variables ****")
        for var in tvars:
            init_string = ""
            if var.name in initialized_variable_names:
            init_string = ", *INIT_FROM_CKPT*"
            tf.logging.info("  name = %s, shape = %s%s", var.name, var.shape,
                        init_string)

        output_spec = None
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            train_op = optimization.create_optimizer(
            total_loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu)

            output_spec = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode,
            loss=total_loss,
            train_op=train_op,
            scaffold_fn=scaffold_fn)
        elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:

            def metric_fn(masked_lm_example_loss, masked_lm_log_probs, masked_lm_ids,
                      masked_lm_weights, next_sentence_example_loss,
                      next_sentence_log_probs, next_sentence_labels):
            """Computes the loss and accuracy of the model."""
            masked_lm_log_probs = tf.reshape(masked_lm_log_probs,
                                             [-1, masked_lm_log_probs.shape[-1]])
            masked_lm_predictions = tf.argmax(
                masked_lm_log_probs, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32)
            masked_lm_example_loss = tf.reshape(masked_lm_example_loss, [-1])
            masked_lm_ids = tf.reshape(masked_lm_ids, [-1])
            masked_lm_weights = tf.reshape(masked_lm_weights, [-1])
            masked_lm_accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(
                labels=masked_lm_ids,
                predictions=masked_lm_predictions,
                weights=masked_lm_weights)
            masked_lm_mean_loss = tf.metrics.mean(
                values=masked_lm_example_loss, weights=masked_lm_weights)

            next_sentence_log_probs = tf.reshape(
                next_sentence_log_probs, [-1, next_sentence_log_probs.shape[-1]])
            next_sentence_predictions = tf.argmax(
                next_sentence_log_probs, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32)
            next_sentence_labels = tf.reshape(next_sentence_labels, [-1])
            next_sentence_accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(
                labels=next_sentence_labels, predictions=next_sentence_predictions)
            next_sentence_mean_loss = tf.metrics.mean(
                values=next_sentence_example_loss)

            return {
                "masked_lm_accuracy": masked_lm_accuracy,
                "masked_lm_loss": masked_lm_mean_loss,
                "next_sentence_accuracy": next_sentence_accuracy,
                "next_sentence_loss": next_sentence_mean_loss,
                "next_sentence_log_probs":  next_sentence_log_probs, ## <<-- add this line
            }

            eval_metrics = (metric_fn, [
            masked_lm_example_loss, masked_lm_log_probs, masked_lm_ids,
            masked_lm_weights, next_sentence_example_loss,
            next_sentence_log_probs, next_sentence_labels
            ])
            output_spec = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode,
            loss=total_loss,
            eval_metrics=eval_metrics,
            scaffold_fn=scaffold_fn,

            )
        else:
            raise ValueError("Only TRAIN and EVAL modes are supported: %s" % (mode))

        return output_spec

    return model_fn
```

Finally in main I try this:

```
    tf.logging.info("***** Running evaluation *****")
    tf.logging.info("  Batch size = %d", FLAGS.eval_batch_size)

    eval_input_fn = input_fn_builder(
        input_files=input_files,
        max_seq_length=FLAGS.max_seq_length,
        max_predictions_per_seq=FLAGS.max_predictions_per_seq,
        is_training=False)

    result = estimator.evaluate(
        input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=FLAGS.max_eval_steps)

    output_eval_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir, "eval_results.txt")
    with tf.gfile.GFile(output_eval_file, "w") as writer:
        tf.logging.info("***** Eval results *****")
        for key in sorted(result.keys()):
            tf.logging.info("  %s = %s", key, str(result[key]))
            writer.write("%s = %s\n" % (key, str(result[key])))
```

The function returns this error messaage:

```
TypeError: Values of eval_metric_ops must be (metric_value, update_op) tuples, given: Tensor("Reshape_7:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32) for key: next_sentence_log_probs
```

How do I get numbers in stead of a Tensor at the output???

I think this has a lot to do with the '.eval()' method and the 'Session'.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the Huggingface transformers repo. I will use that.

https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertForNextSentencePrediction